# interpreting IOPS these Bonnie++ and iostat results

Tags: performance, storage, iops

I am looking to interpret the IOPS from a few runs of bonnie++ using iostat simultaneously and using the benchmarking from this post: 
[Can I determine IOPS on a disk array using bonnie++?](https://serverfault.com/questions/517051/can-i-determine-iops-on-a-disk-array-using-bonnie)

bonnie++ run:

```
/usr/sbin/bonnie++ -d /data -s 128754 -u root:root -qfb
```

2x memory on the /data filesystem.  This system is very fast, with SSDs in a raid6 Array.

Bonnie++ random seeks show **657.9** seeks per second:

```
Version  1.96       ------Sequential Output------ --Sequential Input- --Random-
Concurrency   1     -Per Chr- --Block-- -Rewrite- -Per Chr- --Block-- --Seeks--
Machine        Size K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP  /sec %CP
splunk6-w2- 128754M           695761  97 480604  70           1407252  88 657.9 110
Latency                       32464us   94804us             16869us    7398us
Version  1.96       ------Sequential Create------ --------Random Create--------
splunk6-w2-inf      -Create-- --Read--- -Delete-- -Create-- --Read--- -Delete--
              files  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP
                 16  8057  18 +++++ +++ +++++ +++ +++++ +++ +++++ +++ +++++ +++
Latency               154us     355us     356us     154us      10us      60us
1.96,1.96,splunk6-w2-inf,1,1393273639,128754M,,,,695761,97,480604,70,,,1407252,88,657.9,110,16,,,,,8057,18,+++++,+++,+++++,+++,+++++,+++,+++++,+++,+++++,+++,,32464us,94804us,,16869us,7398us,154us,355us,356us,154us,10us,60us
```

I was running iostat at the same time bonnie++ was generating its test files and tps results are really high:

```
Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
dm-2            292.61      1847.92      2282.89  928897994 1147544976

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.13    0.00    3.73    0.00    0.00   96.15

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
dm-2          41035.00         8.00    328272.00          8     328272

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.06    0.00    6.31    0.00    0.00   93.62

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
dm-2          225280.00         0.00   1802240.00          0    1802240

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.13    0.00    7.09    0.44    0.00   92.35

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
dm-2          251050.00         0.00   2008392.00          0    2008392

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.09    0.00    9.41    0.00    0.00   90.50

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
dm-2          277187.00         8.00   2217488.00          8    2217488
```

I would expect the Bonnie++ stats to be higher: I've tested on older machines showing higher random seeks. What's the best representation of IOPS based on these stats, or should I gather them another way? Since those are the tools I have available, I am currently focusing on iostat and bonnie++.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using mdraid, or hardware RAID? What chunk size? What fs? Did you tune the fs in any way to suit your raid/ssd setup? Asking, because bonnie does not just measure IOPS of the storage, but rather performance of the whole stack. Including fs.

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting? Your results look fine. The `tps` figure is what you should be monitoring if you're specifically trying to determine IOPS. But are you just benchmarking for benchmarking's sake?

The best measure of something like this is a real application or a realistic usage scenario.

Comment: I was not sure what to expect as were migrating Splunk indexers to this new server build with SSD's. That's our next step is to measure indexing rate with a barebones Splunk install, but i wanted to get a general IOPS range...just surprised the TPS value is so high.